# Как узнать размер файла С++?

Tags: c++, файлы, потоки-данных, fstream

В интернете есть несколько вариантов: просто перечитать весь файл (если файл большой, то не подходит из-за скорости), использовать tellg() (не подходит, так как ограничен на аппаратном уровне (не больше 8 гб)).

Ни один из них мне не подходит. Есть ли какой-нибудь иной подход?

Comment: *"ограничен на аппаратном уровне"* - такие сильные заявления следует как-то подкреплять

Answer (score 4, accepted):

См. функцию [`file_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size) из `filesystem`.

Однако не понимаю ваше неприятие `tellg()`. Отлично сработало на 140-гигабайтном файле. В чем вы видите проблемы?

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    ifstream in("BELOFF_2O23.O4.ISO");
    in.seekg(0,ios::end);
    cout << in.tellg();
}
```

выдает 150875752448, `dir` дает

```
05.08.2023  16:19   150 875 752 448 BELOFF_2O23.O4.ISO
```

Что не так?